# ExpressJS - Generate a CSV file on the server side and enable download from the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, json2csv

I am using ExpressJS to develop a web app.

There is a Create button on the page. What I want to achieve is, when the button is clicked, it sends a Post/Get request to the server side, and the server side then triggers a process to generate a CSV file and send it back to the client side for download.

I am thinking of using `json2csv`.

Client side:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/incidents/createTable",
            success: function() {
                // HOW TO GET THE RETURNED DATA TO A DOWNLOADABLE FILE?
            }
        });
```

Server side and `incidents` router (the code snippet that follows was copied from the json2csv official npmjs page):

```
const { AsyncParser } = require('json2csv');
// THIS FUNCTION SHOULD GENERATE A CSV FILE IN MEMORY
router.post("/createTable", async function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("flag 1");  // For flagging

    const fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];
    const opts = { fields };
    const transformOpts = { highWaterMark: 8192 };

    const asyncParser = new AsyncParser(opts, transformOpts);

    console.log("flag 2");  // For flagging
    let csv = '';
    asyncParser.processor
    .on('data', chunk => (csv += chunk.toString()))
    .on('end', () => res.send(csv))
    .on('error', err => console.error(err));
});
```

When I ran the web app and clicked the Create button, the server hung there, it passed "flag 2" and never went pass the `asyncParser.processor`. On the client side, the POST request was also hung there and with no status code.

Comment: Do you mean that 'flag 1' is logged but no 'flag 2' ?

Comment: Sorry for typo. It logged `flag 2` but not `asyncParser.processor`.

Comment: Ok but which data are you given the to processor ?

Comment: the code does not look complete, you are not giving any data to processor. on the doc which you copied the code, the next line should read `asyncParser.input.push(data); // This data might come from an HTTP request, etc.` but you dont have a corresponding line

Comment: You could add [res.attachment('data.csv')](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.attachment) to make the browser download the file but to make that work you can't use ajax. you have to submit a `<form>` the other option is to use something like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) or [StreamSaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js). You could also generate the csv on the client side and trigger a download

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I wanted to have the `createTable` function to generate a CSV but in memory and send back to the client side (via ajax success?). Then the user will be able to download the file.

Comment: if you want to use ajax then you have to generate a ObjectURL from a blob, attach it to a link, add download attribute and trigger a click on it, something which streamsaver and filesaver dose for you. `res.attachment` is useless if it's not navigated to

Comment: @Endless. I would prefer to create the csv file in memory as the file will be rather small than on the server.

Comment: sure you can do that but i was explaining more of how you can save the file not generating it

Answer (score 1):

Finally worked out a solution after doing a lot digging.

Server side:

```
var stream = require('stream');
//...
router.post("/createTable", async function(req, res, next) {
    var fileContents = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({
        sampleTime: '1450632410296',
        sampleData: '1234567890'
    }));

    var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
    readStream.end(fileContents);

    res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + "download.csv");
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');

    readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

Client side:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/incidents/createTable",
        success: function(result) {
            var blob=new Blob([result], {type: 'text/csv'});
            var link=document.createElement('a');

            link.style = "display: none";
            document.body.appendChild(link);

            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.href = url;
            console.log(url);
            link.download="download.csv";
            link.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one part, which is providing the data. Parser won't do anything until you do that. This is also hunging up a request, because `res.send` will never be reached.

Right from the docs:

```
asyncParser.input.push(data); // This data might come from an HTTP request, etc.
asyncParser.input.push(null); // Sending `null` to a stream signal that no more data is expected and ends it.
```

Here is complete code that will produce

```
"field1","field2","field3"
1,2,3
```

on GET /createTable

```
const { AsyncParser } = require('json2csv');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get("/createTable", async function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("flag 1");  // For flagging

    const fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];
    const opts = { fields };
    const transformOpts = { highWaterMark: 8192 };

    const asyncParser = new AsyncParser(opts, transformOpts);

    console.log("flag 2");  // For flagging
    let csv = '';
    asyncParser.processor
      .on('data', chunk => (csv += chunk.toString()))
      .on('end', () => res.send(csv))
      .on('error', err => console.error(err));

    asyncParser.input.push('{ "field1": 1, "field2": 2, "field3": 3 }');
    asyncParser.input.push(null); // Sending `null` to a stream signal that no more data is expected and ends it.
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code. The client side did print out `"field1","field2","field3" 1,2,3`. But this is not what I wanted to achieve. I would like to have the output as a csv file for user to download as stated in the subject title.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file